# Haxe: how to declare "static" methods in an Interface?

Tags: interface, static, haxe

This question has been asked (and probably answered) in the old Haxe forums on babble ... but it appears that that *entire* forum system no longer functions.  Therefore, I'm asking here:

In Haxe, I need to declare an "Interface" to a class which includes a static function, "instance()."  But when I do so:

`You can't declare static fields in interfaces`

So I remove the word "static" from `public function instance() [...]`, and I get this:

`Field instance needed by [...] is missing.`

Apparently a "Catch-22."  But there obviously must be some easy solution.  What is it?

Answer (score 6):

As you stated the language doesn't allow for static fields on interfaces. The choice is intentional. Another thing that doesn't exist is inheriting static fields.

There are several ways to structure your code to avoid such usage that in my point of view it doesn't give you many advantages. A factory pattern or DI approach (I suggest the [minject library](https://github.com/massiveinteractive/minject)) seems the most obvious.

Given the comment below go for a `typedef` instead of an interface:

```
typedef GetInstance = Void -> Void;
```

You can pass that typedef around the same as an interface with the advantage that you can use both static and instance methods to satisfy that signature.

Comment: The use-case is simply that this class has a "public static function instance()" which returns a singleton instance.  The application contains several libraries that need to refer to one another as "extern," and that means they need to know about an interface which includes this function.  In other words, they need to be able to call this function, among others.  Please get specific in your answer ...

Comment: Why would you want to access a static field of a interface? Lets say you have a ISingleton interface, what is the point of doing ISingleton.instance? What would you expect there? Static fields should be called directly or  referenced. I also think it's better to avoid singletons. You can find lot cons on the web about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Singleton](https://github.com/DelishusCake/Singleton) library. Any class that implements Singleton will automatically declare a static "instance" variable and corresponding getter function.

Note: as of this writing, the Haxelib version (1.0.0) is out of date. Download the Git version instead.